# How to find element and his properties in xsd file

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, linq, xsd

I need create db tabels in ms sql server from xsd file. First I load xsd and xml to `DataSet`, then for each `DataColumn` in `DataTable` I create SqlCommand like this:

```
SqlCommand createtable = new SqlCommand("create table " + dt.TableName + " (" + 
dc.ColumnName + "  varchar(max))", conn);
createtable.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

or like this:

```
SqlCommand addcol = new SqlCommand("alter table "+ dt.TableName+" 
add "+dc.ColumnName+" varchar(max)", conn);
addcol.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But I need properties of element/ColumnName from xsd file. For examle like this.

```
<xs:simpleType>
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:Length value="20"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

So I need find `restriction` of xsd element, and dont forget of "parent" element, because some element is xsd scheme have same name ("parent" element - name of `DataTable`).

p.s. I know that `DataColumn` has properties, but only `MaxLenght`. And I know about Altova, but I need "code" realisation.

Update: I create DataSet like this:

```
DataSet temp = new DataSet();
temp.ReadXmlSchema("schema.xsd");            
temp.ReadXml("xml_file.xml");
```

Comment: Regarding your "p.s.": you could use the ExtendedProperties of `DataColumns` / `DataTables` to store additional information like the SqlType.

Comment: @SébastienSevrin I generate DataSet automatically using `ReadXmlSchema` (see update of my question)